# terraform error: Invalid value for module argument

Tags: amazon-web-services, syntax-error, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-modules

I am getting this error in tf plan:

```
Error: Invalid value for module argument

  on ec2_asg.tf line 13, in module "ec2_asg":
  13:   subnets             = [module.vpc.private_subnets]

The given value is not suitable for child module variable "subnets" defined at
.terraform/modules/ec2_asg/variables.tf:388,1-19: element 0: string required.
```

This is the variable in the module:

```
variable "subnets" {
  description = "List of subnets for Application. e.g. ['subnet-8da92df7', 'subnet-9e5dc5f6', 'subnet-497eaf33']"
  type        = list(string)
}
```

This is in the .tf file:

```
  ......
  ......
  scaling_max         = var.scaling_max_bi
  subnets             = [module.vpc.private_subnets]
  security_groups     = [aws_security_group.id]
```

Can someone help me fix this?

Comment: Where does `module.vpc.private_subnets` come from? This is not your `var.private_subnets`.

Comment: @Marcin oh sorry I edited in the right one, pls check, thanks!

Comment: I guess you can try `subnets             = module.vpc.private_subnets` (no square brackets).

Comment: @Marcin it worked, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The **solution** was to change:

```
subnets             = [module.vpc.private_subnets]
```

into

```
subnets             = module.vpc.private_subnets
```